# Художественные средства

Tags: семантика

> Я медленно иду по осеннему лесу, любуясь желтовато-красными красками осени, и слушаю негромкий шёпот листьев, шуршащих под ногами.

Как найти?

1. Какие художественные средства.
2. Словосочетания с примыканием.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Художественные средства: "желтовато-красные краски осени", "негромкий шепот листье".
Словосочетание с примыканием, это словосочетание, зависимое слово которого является наречием, деепричастием или глаголом неопределенной формы. В данном случае: *медленно иду*.

А вообще, делайте домашние задания сами, а то так и останетесь малограмотной, а это, по меньшей мере, стыдно.

Answer (score 1):

Аллитерация: повторяется звук ш, что создаёт эффект шуршащих листьев.
Метафора: шёпот листьев.Цветопись:желтовато - красные краски осени".
Примыкание: иду медленно; иду, любуясь;